# Пропадают элементы в TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Суть проблемы: при большом (не знаю сколько точно, но при ~10-20 всё работает отлично, а добавил 5к+ и начались проблемы) количестве записей в таблице, при добавлении новой строки или изменение элемента, и переключение на другого продавца где есть такой же товар, изменить там товар с таким же именем, и при возвращение обратно эти изменения не отображаются, хотя если смотреть в бд то там сохранены все изменения.

В чем может быть проблема?
[image: Скрин программы]

Вот немного кода

Обновление полей 1..10

```
z1.setOnEditCommit((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ProductEntity, Number> t) -> {
    t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow()).setB1(new BigDecimal(t.getNewValue().toString()));
    //тут запись в бд
});
```

Добавление продукта
//dataForViewDateRead - коллекция которая содержит элементы которые отображаются

```
ProductEntity productEntity = getNullEn();
productEntity.setIdPoint(thisPointEntity);
productEntity.setProduct(nameProduct.getText());
productEntity.setPrice(new BigDecimal(priceProduct.getText()));
productEntity.setDate(Timestamp.valueOf(datePicker.getValue().atStartOfDay()));
dataForViewDateRead.add(DAO.addProduct(productEntity));
```

Comment: Если честно, то мне лично ваше объяснение не понятно. Сомневаюсь, что в таком виде кто-то сможет вам помочь. Постарайтесь более развёрнуто объяснить суть вопроса. Минимизируйте код и выложите компилируемый вариант - возможно, кто-то захочет у себя воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: @LEQADA не уверен что можно как то сократить этот мой код, что бы он сработал. Суть проблемы в том, что при большом количестве данных в FXCollections, данные в этой коллекции почему то то пропадают, при этом никаких ошибок не выходит. И хотелось бы услышать варианты почему так может случаться.

Comment: Проблема может возникать в коде z1.setCellFactory() если вы сами его настроили. Покажите код.